# remove shadow from FusionTables layers using javascript google map api 3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml, google-fusion-tables, dropshadow, leaflet

hi i have polygon Placemarks using fusion tables, when i try to configure styles i am uable to hide shadows, is is possible to do this using google map js api.

see example here

https://www.google.com/fusiontables/embedviz?viz=MAP&q=select+col0+from+13fHuXHIQB55s_C7tpQQFArYMHORjmmThqK9jarQ&h=false&lat=56.168558817410656&lng=2.1851482391250556&z=7&t=1&l=col0

Also do you think such bulky data can be shown in leafletjs using KML. so that i have more control over it.

Comment: I think there is no option to get rid the shadow of PlaceMarks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you aware that you can use your fusion table as a layer on the standard Google Maps API rather than using /embedviz ?

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#FusionTables

That should give you more control over how it's rendered. On a separate note, I'm not sure if this is relevant but I came across it:

https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/articles/fusiontables_styling

Comment: I already checked those links before. They don't provide any information regarding removal of the dropshadow. I haven't found a single public example of FusionTableLayers usage without a dropshadow so far.